# здравствуйте, не подскажете как увести текст placheolderа вверх, чтобы 23 начиналось сверху, а не по середине

Tags: css

[![

```css
  .rek {
  width: 730px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #3c5499;
  margin: 10px 0px 50px 0px;
  
}

::placeholder {
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 1;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Site</title>
</head>

</html>

<body>

  <div class="getin__txt">
    <input class="rek" type="text" placeholder="Your message">
  </div>
</body>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DUWV.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DUWV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно Вам стоит использовать вместо тега `<input ... />` тег `<textarea></textarea>`

```css
  .rek {
  width: 730px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #3c5499;
  margin: 10px 0px 50px 0px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Site</title>
</head>
</html>

<body>
  <div class="getin__txt">
    <textarea class="rek">Можно использовать textarea вместо input если хотите получить многострочный текст.</textarea>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: госпаде, какой я идиот, спасибо